# How to add rolling filters in dashboard

Tags: dashboard

I want to add custom filters to dashboards, that means from 05-02-2014 to 31-12-2014
can any one please guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Last 2 months, Last 3 Months
Rolling filter, as you said we cannot add the custom filters like date range through UI
but may possible using VF pages/ components

Comment: thank you can you give me the references for the VF components in Dashboard